# Change default GUID serialization format

Tags: asp.net, serialization, asp.net-web-api, guid

By default, the JSON and XML serializers in Web API 2 just call `ToString()` to serialize out a Guid, which means it includes dashes: `fd190000-5532-8477-e053-9a16ce0af828`. I'd really like to change the default serialization to the format returned by `ToString("N")`, which does not include dashes: `fd19000055328477e0539a16ce0af828`.

I found [this article](http://tinymission.com/post/custom-serialization-for-json-properties-in-web-api) on creating a JsonConverter and overriding the `WriteJson()` method to use `ToString("N")`. That worked fine for JSON, but I haven't found anything similar for XML serialization.

Is there a way to implement this only once, regardless of how many MediaTypeFormatters are present? If not, how can I override XML serialization as well?